# how to do topological sort with lists in python

Tags: python, list, networkx, topological-sort

I just started doing my bachelor thesis and what I am trying to do is to create an algorithm that will provide personalized suggestions regarding course selection based on past academic performance. I am learning and using python and till now I have created a list of courses and a list of prerequisites that looks like this:

`[['CS101'], ['CS105'], ['CS106', 'CS105'], ['CS107'], ['CS130'], ['CS151', 'CS105', 'MATH101'], ['CS180'], ['CS201', 'CS151'], ['CS205', 'CS105'], ...]`

So for example in order to take `CS101` you do not need to have taken any other course, but for you to take `CS106` you have to already have taken `CS105`. Now, I have to do topological sort and even though I found some code from a similar problem that was provided here in Stack Overflow, it does not work. The solution was this (I modified only the part of `my_lists` in order to work for my code):

```
        import networkx as nx

        my_lists = data.prerequisites
        my_graph = nx.DiGraph()
        for path in my_lists:
            my_graph.add_nodes_from(path)
            my_graph.add_path(path)

        ts = nx.topological_sort(my_graph)
        print(ts)
```

where data.prerequisites is the list that was created in another python file(data.py). The problem is that when I run this it gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'add_path'

I searched for documentation of `networkx 2.4` and there is nothing indicating with what they replaced the `add_path()`. There was one solution for this error but it does not work anymore since the solution was given in 2011 and the `add_path()` was completely removed in 2019. I tried to use other examples from the internet but I couldn't find a proper one for lists. Should I try to find a completely different approach or there is a small easy solution like this one? Because a lot of them I cannot really understand.

Comment: This is a popular and maintained library. Search for the library name ('NetworkX'), go to the documentation link. It has up to date information and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of [`add_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.add_path.html) the new way to call the method is

```
nx.add_path(my_graph, path)
```

and as additional hint, you don't need to call `my_graph.add_nodes_from(path)` since the nodes are added together with the edges.